# Elastic search - How to increase the _score in elastic search document

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have a document with less _score which is not retrieved at the query time when i give size:100. I need to make the document available in top 25 results. How to achieve this ? Is there any option to increase the _score manually ?

Comment: Just add a "boost" field or similar with a numerical value and order by that first in your query (and by score second).

Comment: you want manually boost just 1 doc?i'm pretty sure it's not the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: I need to boost a document based on a integer field. Suppose if i have max_doc field with 10, 100 then 100 should come first

Comment: got you, will answer to you in 10-20 mins

Answer (score 1):

I will describe one of the possible ways to do the trick

You could use **function_score** to boost the score based on some functions:

> The function_score query provides several types of score functions.
>
> script_score
>
> weight
>
> random_score
>
> field_value_factor
>
> decay functions: gauss, linear, exp

Example, that will use the **field_value_factor** to boost the score by multiplying the score:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": "_score * doc['popularity'].value"
      },
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

To enable this dynamic scoring you need to alter your yml config file with lines depending on the version of Elastic:

It's either (at least it's the way for 2.4)

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
```

or something like:

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

For more information regarding dynamic scripts - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting (you could select the version of Elastic that you are using)

For more inromation on function score and types of functions: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html